# conditional rendering in react using "if" how does the code reevaluate itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm grabbing some data from a redux action to pull into my React component. In the render() method, I am using an if/else check to see if that data was pulled in. IF the data is null and the "loading" boolean is still true, I want to display a spinner. ELSE - show the data.

When I hit the webpage, the component will show the spinner for half a second, as it's still null, then once the data is pulled in, it will show that.

my question is, in traditional JS, if the "if" statement is reached and the profile is still null will it not just stay on the spinner? Since that if/else expression on page load showed null should it not just stay on my spinner if that was the condition that was met on page load? How does it go back to that statement after the first run and hit the else block afterwards?

```
render() {
     const {profile, loading} = this.props.profile;
     let profileContent;

     if(profile === null || loading){
         profileContent = <Spinner/>;
     } else {
         profileContent = (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                <Link to="/profiles">Back To Profiles</Link>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6"></div>
                </div>
                <ProfileHeader/>
                <ProfileAbout/>
                <ProfileCreds/>
                <ProfileGithub/>

            </div>
         );
     }
```

Comment: Because render isn't only called once. I'd recommend reading up on the basics of React, or even just putting a console.log in.

Comment: Thanks! Still learning React :)

Answer (score 0):

A React Component works by calling the render() function whenever the component state changes by default.

There are ways to modify this behavior by adding component lifecycle methods to your component.

Here is the official React documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Great, that would make sense! Thanks for the resource.